# Azure Speech SDK with FastAPI web Socket not working inside docker and callbacks not sending back websocket bytes

Tags: azure, websocket, fastapi, azure-sdk-python, azure-speech

I am trying to build a real time speech recognizer with azure SDK and FastAPI with websocket, I am sending base64 encoded binary string as input, The azure session starts recognizes text and prints in connected events, but I want to send back recognized text to websocket so I have a callback ,but looks like the print inside callback is working but the send is not working.

Please let me know what is the issue if some oen is able to help

```
 async def process_stream(stream,data,speech_recognizer,websocket):


    def recognized_callback(evt):
        recognized_text = evt.result.text
        print("I am in websocket callback : " + str(recognized_text)+" "+str(websocket))

        async def send_data():
            await websocket.send_text(recognized_text)

        asyncio.gather(send_data())


    # The number of bytes to push per buffer
    n_bytes = 4096
    data = io.BytesIO(data)

    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(recognized_callback)

    # Start pushing data until all data has been read from the file
    try:
        speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
        while True:

            frames = data.read(n_bytes // 2)
            print('read {} bytes'.format(len(frames)))
            if not frames:
                speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
                break
            stream.write(frames)

            await asyncio.sleep(0.03)
    finally:
        stream.close()
@app.websocket("/asr/en")
async def root(websocket:WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    audio_format = AudioStreamFormat(
        channels=1,
        samples_per_second=16000,
        bits_per_sample=16
    )
    stream = speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream(audio_format)

    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config,
                                                   audio_config=speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=stream))

    try:
        while True:
            # Receive audio data from the client

            data = await websocket.receive_bytes()
            break

        await process_stream(stream,data,speech_recognizer,websocket)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

LOGS:

INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [62395]
INFO:     Started server process [62529]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     ('127.0.0.1', 53888) - "WebSocket /asr/en" [accepted]
INFO:     connection open
SESSION STARTED: SessionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d)
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=4011e2273ad742aa9e2df99eb3e8a854, text="thank you for", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=8bc91a19b5c2433d9fcc4dbe5125ea9c, text="thank you for contact", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=8ad3f7d5a8dc40e09fdab8dbaa13fc89, text="thank you for contacting", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=49d386798e3d4ebb8172a9b681d929fc, text="thank you for contacting us", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
RECOGNIZED: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=f1d16bcf07da4b4ea2345e38b35c0300, text="Thank you for contacting us.", reason=ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech))
/Users/parikshit.mukherjee/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/./main.py:37: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'root..send_text_async' was never awaited
send_text_async(evt.result.text)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=a16037fd2bec4790be32ec31b7430126, text="lands", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=508fa0fc387c43779c548dcc966133f7, text="lands had", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=8de79e5f5ac54b919cb8987dde425bae, text="yan's incorrectly", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=bfa9673b38be481d9a07263df3643794, text="lands had currently busy", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
RECOGNIZED: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=382841509bba4ae68d5507cd594f2a9d, text="Yan's incorrectly busy.", reason=ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech))
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=5c05c9b20acc4d679a547bef5c97b473, text="how", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=c3b7c690ff61450ca2cb02f9a17d70e5, text="how pain", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=b1ee047ae4c143b78f17b75e6d306dca, text="how pain is", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=f396e7705c894f63a485378d0490d7f1, text="how pain is very", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=b502f32f7a1d47508a9af27b47abe24f, text="how pain is very important", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
RECOGNIZING: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=618e549690534b7ca20e07d087de202f, text="how pain is very important to us", reason=ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech))
RECOGNIZED: SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=02f165702334418a8635a40c4c16ea1d, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=8af7a291290e45329b38bd172a1ddf65, text="How pain is very important to us.", reason=ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech))
/Users/parikshit.mukherjee/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cognitiveservices/speech/speech.py:652: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'root..session_stopped_cb' was never awaited
cb(payload)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
INFO:     connection closed

Comment: read 3200 bytes
read 3200 bytes
read 3200 bytes
read 3200 bytes
read 3200 bytes
read 3200 bytes
read 3200 bytes
read 1244 bytes
read 0 bytes
2024-02-26 10:00:06,679 - app.routers.conversation - INFO - Stream Pushed
SESSION STARTED: SessionEventArgs(session_id=5d00444cd7604079bad2bb567054e389)
2024-02-26 10:00:06,688 - app.routers.conversation - INFO - Started Recognition

Comment: It gets stuck here

Comment: Are you using SDK in C# code?

Comment: @Dasari Kamali No python

Comment: Can you provide your complete code?

Comment: I see that speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition() is not invoking callbacks in FastAPI setup but standalone code works

Comment: Hi, I got the text [output](https://i.imgur.com/f1c8pzc.png) with the **base64** data in Postman using **Fastapi** and **web socket** in Python only.

Comment: Did you get the speech-to-text output with Fastapi and WebSocket without docker? are you getting errors when you use docker?

Comment: @DasariKamali I can only see the console prints from the lambdas but the callback function wher eI have the logic to send back to websocket is not invoked. Can you please share your code that will be helpful

Comment: Even without Docker I dont see any response going to postman from callback

Comment: @DasariKamali I have updated the code to help undrstand the goal I am trying to achieve ,so its not just a one time recognition, it is continuous recognition through streams only

Answer (score 0):

*I tried the FastAPI with WebSocket code below to convert speech-to-text using a Dockerfile.*

**Code :**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import base64
import os
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

app = FastAPI()

speech_key = "<speech_key>"
service_region = "<speech_region>"

def speech_recognize_continuous_from_stream(audio_data):
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=audio_data)
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()
    return result.text if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech else ""

@app.post("/convert")
async def convert_audio(audioBase64: dict):
    try:
        audio_bytes = base64.b64decode(audioBase64['audioBase64'])
        with open("temp.wav", "wb") as audio_file:
            audio_file.write(audio_bytes)
        transcription_result = speech_recognize_continuous_from_stream("temp.wav")
        os.unlink("temp.wav")
        return {"text": transcription_result}
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    try:
        await websocket.accept()
        print("WebSocket connection accepted")
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            print("Received data from client:", data[:50])  
            text = "Speech recognition failed"
            await websocket.send_text(text)
    except Exception as e:
        print("WebSocket error:", e)
```

**Output :**

The following code ran successfully:

[image]

I received the **text** output with the input **base64** data as follows:

```
{
    "audioBase64": "your_base64_audio_data_here"
}
```

[image]

Next, I added the **Dockerfile** below to the code:

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app
COPY main.py .
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

I successfully built, ran, and checked the logs of the **Dockerfile** using the following commands:

```
docker build -t my_fastapi_app .
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 my_fastapi_app
docker logs <CONTAINER_ID>
```

[image]

Comment: in your code you are reading a file, my requirement is continuous ASR with the data sent as input binary base64 string, any ways thanks for the help. you need to pass data = await websocket.receive_text() to speech recognizer

Comment: @ParikshitMukherjee I am not reading any file, I just converted the **base64** data to text output in Postman with the above code.

Comment: My Requirement is continuous speech recognition , so the input of websocket needs to be continuously passed there is noneed for any file creation as wav

Comment: @ParikshitMukherjee I will update the answer with continuous speech, give me sometime.

Comment: Sure I have updated the code that I have working till the print inside the callback ,only the send_text is not getting executed